# Сортировка массива точек, расположенных вдоль замкнутого контура.

Tags: алгоритм, сортировка

Есть массив точек *`X`*`{x,y}`, образующих замкнутый гладкий контур ([аэродинамический профиль](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB:Airfoil_Evoultion.jpg)). Точки изначально расположены в массиве хаотично и неравномерно. Подскажите алгоритм сортировки, позволяющий расположить точки по логическому порядку.

**UPD.** Лимит коментариев((. Точки на профиле расположены примерно так (в большинстве случаев)

[image]

т.е. в местах с большим радиусом кривизны пореже и наоборот. Шаг точеки может быть как маленьким, так и относительно большим. (@alexz)

Answer (score 2):

Или я неправильно понял условие или однозначного решения нет.
Например на приведеной ниже картинке точки можно расположить как минимум в 2-х разных порядках:
[image: Пример]

**UPD:** если предположить, что профиль выпуклый, то можно просто найти выпуклую оболочку множества (одним из алгоритмов из приведенных в конце [статьи на Википедии](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0)), а затем взять точки в том порядке, в котором они встречаются в выпуклой оболочке.

Comment: Немного я не полно описал. Не помню как это правильно назвать (такой вид контура), но такой ситуации в моем случае не может быть вроде. Контуры представляют собой [аэродинамический профиль][1].

[1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB:Airfoil_Evoultion.jpg

Comment: Все эти профили, кроме Жуковского, выпуклые. Вы это имели ввиду?

Comment: Да-да. Именно так

Comment: Идея с оболочкой интересна. Но как быть с профилями типа того самого Жуковского? Или хотябы как отличить такие профили?

Answer (score 2):

1. Берем произвольную точку.
2. Вычеркиваем из общего списка неразобранных точек, помещаем в выходной список.
3. Находим точку, которая ближе всего к исходной. Используем обычную декартовскую меру расстояния.
4. Вычеркиваем ее из списка неразобранных, помещаем в выходной список.
5. Если есть еще неразобранные точки - идем к п.3.

По замечаниям и обсуждениям усисливаем позицию :-) :

> Классический сплайн одной переменной строится так: область определения разбивается на конечное число отрезков, на каждом из которых сплайн совпадает с некоторым алгебраическим полиномом. Максимальная степень из использованных полиномов называется степенью сплайна. Разность между степенью сплайна и получившейся гладкостью называется дефектом сплайна. Например, непрерывная ломаная есть сплайн степени 1 и дефекта 1.

Если простая декартова мера оказывается недостаточной, можно воспользоваться старыми добрыми сплайнами. Заметьте, не я усложняю задачу... строим сплайн для комбинаций из 4 ближайших точек и выбираем ту, для которой степень слайна оказывается минимальной. Но начинать надо с одного из концов фигуры - чтобы мы сразу начали двигаться по одной из долей - верхней или нижней.

Comment: Идея хорошая. Но (опять же моя ошибка в вопросе), точки могут быть расположены очень не равномерно. И необходимая следующая точка может быть по расстоянию дальше какой-нибудь "ненужной".

Comment: По-моему, если это гладкий контур, то вряд ли :-)  Разумеется, эффективность метода во многом зависит от частоты дискретизации.  Если мы говорим о фигуре профиля, то нужно позаботиться о том, чтобы на участках с малой толщиной отсчеты брались чаще - хотя бы в полтора раза чаще чем толщина профиля.

Comment: Это факт. Некоторые участки могут быть близкими к прямой - в этих местах точки расположены редко.

Answer (score 1):

По мне - для начала достаточно отсортировать по возрастанию координат. Например, по x. Если будут точки с одинаковой координатой x - отсортировать их по y. Теперь если их соединить получается ломаная. Зигзагообразная. А теперь нужно придумать как разбить точки на два класса - на одну кривую аэродинамического профиля и на другую. Пока идеи нет как это сделать.

Если фигура стабильно выпуклая - можно заюзать алгоритмы [триангуляции](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5). Они как раз делают массив "ребер" на выходе, а затем уже можно выбрать среди них нужные.

Comment: С триангуляцией немного непонятно как потом ребра выбирать. После триангуляции, как мне кажется, задача не сильно упростится. А вот с отбором по координатам конечно можно придумать что-нибудь. С плоско-выпуклыми и выпуклыми все понятно. Первая половина массива отсортирована по x && y выше "базовой линии", вторая половина - y ниже линии или на ней. А как быть с выпукло-вогнутыми (тот же Жуковский)? Какие предложения?

Comment: Сложный вопрос. Можно попробовать выстроить контур, взяв произвольную точку, найти ближайшую. Затем найти ближайшую к любой из двух, и поместить в голову списка или в хвост в зависимости от расстояния до головы/хвоста. Затем повторить для оставшихся (найти ближайшую к крайним из найденых). И т.д.
Сильно зависит от исходных данных (например как выбираются точки, какой профиль, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

1. Находим центр. Точка с коорд x0 = средняя X всех точек, y0 аналогично. Вариант: (xmin+xmax)/2, и y так же
2. Вычисляете угол между центром и точкой (центр в полярной системе координат) в диапазоне  от 0 до 2pi (или -pi до pi)
3. Сортируете в нужном Вам порядке обхода

Но это только для выпуклых фигур.

Пример неправильного порядка при обходе против часовой стрелки (для вогнутого участка)
Профиль конечно от огурца, но тут уж увы.

[image]

Вот тут одна из проблем автоматического построения

[image]

Comment: Мне кажется это ближе всего к истине. Подойдет и для выпукло-вогнутых профилей если правильно определить центр. Если центр будет находиться внутри профиля (даже выпукло-вогнутого) то угол от "нужной" точки к точке будет постоянно возрастать (или убывать). С абсциссой все просто. А как правильно найти ординату центра так, чтобы она была внутри профиля?

Comment: Вряд ли это хорошая идея. Потому что при центре внутри профиля некоторые точки нижней вогнутой части будут идти в неправильном порядке.

Comment: А что есть неправильный порядок? И почему некоторые точки? Какие некоторые? Если точки будут идти в порядке "по часовой или против" начиная с точки с Xmax, то это идеальный вариант. Так как потом это все еще нарисовать надо (иногда сплайном).

Comment: Блииин. Да. Мои извинения! Все больше склоняюсь к тому, что сначала нужно выделить нижнюю и верхнюю дуги, а выполнять сортировку отдельно для каждой, а потом каким-то способом лепить общий массив. Есть идеи?

Comment: Проблема глобальная или нужно решение конкретной задачи? Возможно надо "что-то в консерватории подправить". Т.е. каким образом Вы получаете координаты точек? Может быть что-то там? Допустим, точки скалываются с чертежа на регулярной основе (ну кроме вставки ранее пропущенных при съёме).

Comment: Моя задача заключается в следующем - есть база (скопище csv) профилей. Довольно большая, чтобы править ее вручную. Так вот в этих файлах бывают точки по порядку от носика профиля до концовки, а бывают вперемешку. О S-образных профилях и не задумывался. Проблема++.

Comment: Ну в тексте, из которого взята эта картинка написано, что это профиль крыла бесхвостки. А шаг точек меньше расстояния между ближайшими точками верхней и нижней линий?